# How do I stop and smoothly continue parallex background?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi I created a parallex background and want to stop the parallex background by disabling the script after colliding into a trigger. However, I ran into the problem where the continuation of the the parallex back to when I am out of the collider snaps some parts of the background into another position before returning to the parallex background. Here are the scripts I am using:

**The parallex background script that is placed in all background gameobjects**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Parallex : OffParallex
{
    public float length, startpos;
    public GameObject Maincamera;
    public float parallaxEffect;
    public bool canParallex = true;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        if (canParallex == true)
        {
            startpos = transform.position.x;
            canParallex = false;
        }
        
        
        length = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().bounds.size.x;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float temp = (Maincamera.transform.position.x * (1 - parallaxEffect));
        float dist = (Maincamera.transform.position.x * parallaxEffect);

        transform.position = new Vector3(startpos + dist, 0, transform.position.z);

        if (temp > startpos + length) { startpos += length; }
        else if (temp < startpos - length) { startpos -= length; }
    }

  
}
```

**Parallex script holds the empty game object with the trigger**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class OffParallex : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject[] gameObjects;

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        gameObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("background");
        foreach (var gameObject in gameObjects)
        {
            var parallexScript = gameObject.GetComponent<Parallex>();
            parallexScript.enabled = false;

        }
    }
    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        foreach (var gameObject in gameObjects)
        {
            var parallexScript = gameObject.GetComponent<Parallex>();
            parallexScript.enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

- tried using a Boolean check to disable however the same effect happens